# Find the Domain and Sketch the Graph of the Function $h(x)= \frac{3x+|x|}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\begin{align*}
h(x) & =\dfrac{3x+|x|}{x}\\   
     & = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{3x+|x|}{x} & \text{if $x > 0$}\\
\dfrac{3x + |-x|}{x} & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

I am confused as to whether the $-x$ replaces $x$ for all $x$'s for the lower part of the piecewise function.

In a video I saw the tutor only place an $-x$ in the area where the absolute value is located. Is he performing a short cut?

Please explain.

Comment: $h$ is $4$ if $x > 0,$ not defined at $x = 0$ and  $2$ if $x < 0$. just evaluate $h$ for any positive and a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$|x|=
\begin{cases}
x &\text{if } x\ge0\\
-x &\text{if } x < 0\\ 
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is only the $x$ inside the absolute value that changes sign at $x = 0$.

The absolute value of $x$ is the distance of $x$ from $0$.  For $x \geq 0$, $|x| = x$.  For $x < 0$, $|x| = -1 \cdot x = -x$.  Hence, 
$$|x| = 
\begin{cases}
x & \text{if $x \geq 0$}\\
-x & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}$$
Thus,
\begin{align*}
h(x) & = \frac{3x + |x|}{x}\\
     & = 3 + \frac{|x|}{x}\\
     & =
\begin{cases}
3 + \dfrac{x}{x} & \text{if $x > 0$}\\[2 mm]
3 + \dfrac{-x}{x} & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}
\\
& = 
\begin{cases}
3 + 1 & \text{if $x > 0$}\\
3 - 1 & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}
\\
& = 
\begin{cases}
4 & \text{if $x > 0$}\\
2 & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
and $h(x)$ is undefined if $x = 0$ since division by zero is undefined.